# Operations within matrix avoiding for loops

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a rather simple question but I can't get the proper result in MATLAB.

I am writing a code in Matlab where I have a 200x3 matrix. This data corresponds to the recording of 10 different points, for each of which I took 20 frames.

This is just in order to account for the error in the measuring system. So now I want to calculate the 3D coordinates of each point from this matrix by calculating an average of the measured independent coordinates.

An example (for 1 point with 3 measurements) would be:

```
MeasuredFrames (Point 1) =
   x         y         z
1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
1.1000    2.2000    2.9000
0.9000    2.0000    3.1000

Point = mean(MeasuredFrames(1:3, :))

Point =

1.0000    2.0667    3.0000
```

Now I want to get this result but for 10 points, all stored in a [200x3] array, in intervals of 20 frames.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so basically you want to do something like mean(MeasuredFrames(1:20,:)) followed by mean(MeasuredFrames(21:40,:)) all the way to mean(MeasuredFrames(181:200,:)) without using a loop structure?

Comment: Something like `Des_col=1:20:200; Point=mean(MeasuredFrames(Des_col,:)`  ?

Comment: Yes that was my goal!
I was trying a lot of ideas like that one but could not get the right result... 

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the **Image processing toolbox** [**`blockproc`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) could be an option:

```
A = blockproc(data,[20 3],@(x) mean(x.data,1))
```

**If not** the following using [**`permute`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) with [**`reshape`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) works as well:

```
B = permute(mean(reshape(data,20,10,3),1),[2,3,1])
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
%// transform data to 3D-Matrix 
a = reshape(data,20,10,3);
%// avarage in first dimension
b = mean(a,1);
%// transform back to 10x3 matrix
c = permute(b,[2,3,1])
```

---

**Some sample data:**

```
x = [ 1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
      1.1000    2.2000    2.9000
      0.9000    2.0000    3.1000
      1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
      1.1000    2.2000    2.9000
      0.9000    2.0000    3.1000
      1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
      1.1000    2.2000    2.9000
      0.9000    2.0000    3.1000
      1.1000    2.2000    2.9000]
data = kron(1:20,x.').';
```

---

```
    A = B =

    1.5150    3.1200    4.4850
    3.5350    7.2800   10.4650
    5.5550   11.4400   16.4450
    7.5750   15.6000   22.4250
    9.5950   19.7600   28.4050
   11.6150   23.9200   34.3850
   13.6350   28.0800   40.3650
   15.6550   32.2400   46.3450
   17.6750   36.4000   52.3250
   19.6950   40.5600   58.3050
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to make blockproc work, but the permute function on the reshaped data does just the work!

I really appreciate your help. Awesome!

Comment: arf ... I didn't see you added the solution without the extra toolbox. My answer is redundant now. Although the reshaping is done differently, this is essentially the same method.

Comment: @Slash I made a mistake and corrected it, please recheck.

Comment: I am looking at it right now, but I got the right solution reshaping in blocks of (20, [ ], 3)... Anyways, these are the functions I needed so now it's just a matter of playing with the. Thanks a lot again! @thewaywewalk

Comment: @Slash of course, 10 points à 20 samples, I got confused. Please consider accepting one of the answer to mark the problem as solved. (green check mark on the left)

Comment: Sure I did not know I had to do that! Thanks for everything @thewaywewalk

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have access to the `blockproc` function, you can do it with a combination of `reshape`:

```
np = 20 ;                       %// number of points for averaging

tmp = reshape( A(:) , np,[] ) ; %// unfold A then group by "np"
tmp = mean(tmp);                %// calculate mean for each group
B   = reshape(tmp, [],3 ) ;     %// reshape back to nx3 matrix
```

In your case, replace `A` by `MeasuredFrames` and `B` by `Points`, and group in one line:

```
Points = reshape(mean(reshape( MeasuredFrames (:) , np,[] )), [],3 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication can be used:

```
N=20; 
L=size(MeasuredFrames,1); 
Points = sparse(ceil((1:L)/N), 1:L, 1)*MeasuredFrames/N;
```